# How to disable a people picker x (cross) in a field in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

I have tried to disable a people picker in a field. If I use ng-disable, it doesn't disabling the people picker. I have tried the code bellow, but it requires time interval of 5 secs.

```
$("input.sp-peoplepicker-editorInput[title='Enter a name or email address...']").prop('disabled', true);
```

Any suggestions other than this code ?